# What triggers a battle event in timeline?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

In Age of Empires 2, what is the trigger for drawing a battle event in the Achievements timeline? It seems to be very far from actual happenings, but I just can't get what is a "battle" for the AOE2 engine. For example, often an (kind of) extintion event is considered not a battle.

[image: battle event]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [source](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_battle_event_in_age_of_Empires_II_The_Age_of_Kings_mean) a Battle Event is a one of the following:

- Skirmish between at least 2 players
- A huge battle between at least 2 armies

It happens often after long passive (peace) phases and it can happen only 3 times. The attacking party / aggressor gets the Battle Event, this is why Yellow does not have a Battle Event.

In your example the 3 Battle Events for orange and green are over. Furthermore a Battle Even occurs when the armies first clash, so if you overrun your enemy in say 5 minutes then only the first "encounter" is considered a Battle Event.

Answer (score 0):

I love age of empires 2, i think battle events do not occur as many times as i think it occurs. When i have a 75-100 army and sweep a party of 50 enemies withing 25 seconds (which i do) i wont get the mark. But when like 150 soldiers from 4 other players is fired at me over a time period of 5 minutes and my bombard towers or keeps or castles etc. kill them, i do get a mark...

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If you have another question, please ask it by
clicking the [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=age-of-empires-2)
button.